# If checkbox is checked, apply css to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If checkbox is checked, apply css to href

My HTML:

```
<a href="#"">             
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">0-3 Months
</a>
```

I do not have access to the HTML itself (SaaS Environment) to edit the CSS or to add an ID, name, or class. So the logic must be if any checkbox is checked.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add an event to input, like onclick, and when it is fired, you change the class of tag a?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an input inside an anchor.

Comment: and what does it mean 'css to href'?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Use jQuery.

```
$().ready(function() {
    var selected_option = $('#mySelectBox option:selected');

    if(selected_option) {
        // do something
        $('#SOMEELEMENT').css("background-color", "green");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

In this simple example, when you click at checkbox it will apply a red background at tag A (href)

```
  <html>

  <style type="text/css">        
  .myNewCSS {
    background-color: red
  }
  </style>

  <a href="#" class="x">             
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="test(this)"/> 0-3 Months
  </a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(chk){
      chk.parentNode.className = "myNewCSS";
    }
  </script>

  </html>
```

Comment: Now I realized that you can't change the HTML, so my solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean apply styles to `<a>` then it is not possible to do purely with css. You need to use javascript for that

Answer (score 0):

You can actually select checked inputs with CSS in modern browsers:

```
input:checked {outline: 2px solid red;}
```